# !syncblk identify waiting threads

Tags: debugging, windbg

when I ssued !syncblk command on a deadlocked application from windbg, I got 
the following output. It shows which thread holds the lock. But it does not 
indicate which threads are waiting for the lock. How can I identify the 
threads that are waiting? .

```
0:004> !syncblk 
Index SyncBlock MonitorHeld Recursion Owning Thread Info SyncBlock Owner 
2      0016d12c  3           1        0014b1c0 1ab8 0    01292e3c System.Object 
----------------------------- 
Total 2 
CCW 0 
RCW 0 
ComClassFactory 0 
Free 0
```

Comment: did you read that article at link I posted in your last question, on how to debug deadlocks?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I missed this when I read the article first. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at all of the managed stacks using `~*e!clrstack`. If a thread is waiting to acquire a lock, you should see some appropriate frames in it's stack (e.g, `Monitor.TryEnter`).

Answer (score 1):

If you're troubleshooting a deadlock problem, your first action should be to load [SOSEX.dll](http://www.stevestechspot.com/) and try the `!dlk` command, as it will identify deadlocks based on `Monitor` and `ReaderWriteLock`. It will even pinpoint the exact spot in the source code.

In some cases the `!dlk` command doesn't identify deadlocks as expected. In that case you need to use `!syncblock` as per your question. To find what thread is trying to acquire a specific lock, you can use `~*e!clrstack` as @Liran points out. However, you can also use `~*e!dso` (which will dump references on the stack for the different threads) and look for references to the lock object.